# Python - Intra-package importing when package modules are sometimes used as standalone?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-import

Sorry if this has already been answered using terminology I don't know to search for.

I have one project:

```
project1/
    class1.py
    class2.py
```

Where `class2` imports some things from `class1`, but each has its own `if __name__ == '__main__'` that uses their respective classes I run frequently. But then, I have a second project which creates a subclass of each of the classes from `project1`. So I would like `project1` to be a package, so that I can import it into `project2` nicely:

```
project2/
    project1/
        __init__.py
        class1.py
        class2.py
    subclass1.py
    subclass2.py
```

However, I'm having trouble with the importing with this. If I make `project1` a package then inside `class2.py` I would want to import `class1.py` code using `from project1.class1 import class1`. This makes `project2` code run correctly. But now when I'm trying to use `project1` not as a package, but just running code from directly within that directory, the `project1` code fails (since it doesn't know what `project1` is). If I set it up for `project1` to work directly within that directory (i.e. the import in `class2` is `from class1 import Class1`), then this import fails when trying to use `project1` as a package from `project2`.

Is there a way to have it both ways (use `project1` both as a package and not as a package)? If there is a way, is it a discouraged way and I should be restructuring my code anyway? Other suggestions on how I should be handling this? Thanks!

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, the problem arrises because `subclass2` imports `class2` which in turn imports `class1`. Depending on which way `class2` imports `class1` the import will fail from `project2` or from `project1` because one sees `project1` as a package while the other sees it as the working directory.

**EDIT 2**

I'm using Python 3.5. Apparently this works in Python 2, but not in my current version of python.

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing a nuance of your request, but you should just be able to import the project1 classes into project2 using `from project1 import class1`, then use the code via class1.function(). It shouldn't matter that you have `if __name__ == "__main__"` in each file... Then importing class1 into class2 is still `from class1 import function`.

Comment: @chrxr: The problem comes up when I try to import `class2` in `project2`. Since `class2` imports `class1` then depending on how I preform the import *within class2* the import will either fail from `project2`'s point of view (if import it as `from class1 import Class1`) or `project1`'s (if I import it as `from project1.class1 import class1`). This is because there is an import chain. `subclass2` imports `class2` imports `class1`.

Comment: When you want to run a submodule you should use the `-m` switch. I.e. instead of doing `python /path/to/my/package1/class1.py` you should do `python -m package1.class1` (Obviously your `package1` package should be in the `PYTHONPATH` or you should be in the parent directory).  By the way: I would simply *avoid* what you are doing: clearly separate class definitions and scripts and *never* run `package1`. Write a *separate* file that imports the classes from `package1` and does what it has to do... it's just simpler, cleaner, less error prone.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 2: Added code to class2.py to attach the parent directory to the PYTHONPATH to comply with how Python3 module imports work.

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Removed relative import of Class1.

Folder structure:

```
project2
  - class3.py
  - project1
    - __init__.py
    - class1.py
    - class2.py
```

*project2/project1/class1.py*

```
class Class1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Class1, self).__init__()
        self.name = "DAVE!"

    def printname(self):
        print(self.name)

def run():
    thingamy = Class1()
    thingamy.printname()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

*project2/project1/class2.py*

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

from class1 import Class1

class Class2(Class1):
    def childMethod(self):
      print('Calling child method')

def run():
    thingamy = Class2()
    thingamy.printname()
    thingamy.childMethod()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

*project2/class3.py*

```
from project1.class2 import Class2
from project1.class1 import Class1

class Class3(Class2):
    def anotherChildMethod(self):
      print('Calling another child method')

def run():
    thingamy = Class3()
    thingamy.printname()
    thingamy.anotherChildMethod()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

With this setup each of class1, 2 and 3 can be run as standalone scripts.

Comment: Oh strange! This works in Python 2, but gives the error I'm getting in Python 3! (i.e. `ImportError: No module named 'class1'`) (When updating the print statements) I'm using Python 3. Let me make sure that's known in the question. I didn't know it would make a difference.

Comment: So in other words, when I run the code you just posted in Python 2, everything works as I want it to. But in Python 3.5, I get the import error (after I fix the `print` statements to fit the Python 3 syntax). Other than the print statements, I didn't adjust the code.

Comment: Gotcha! Need to use a relative import in class2.py. This was added in Python3 to remove ambiguity in import location.

Comment: In Python 3 modules are no longer searched in the directory of the importing file.

Comment: @chrxr Using the relative import you can't run `class2.py` alone anymore.

Comment: Thanks @timakro. The code above should now work, assuming that class1.py is in the same directory as class2.py.

Comment: So in the end, you still have to specifically adjust the system path in some way? There's no way to do it just with the imports then? Upvoted for all the effort in any case!

Comment: I'm afraid it seems that is the case if you want to import the module into a project in a different directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could run `class2.py` from inside the `project2` folder, i.e. with the current working directory set to the `project2` folder:

```
user@host:.../project2$ python project1/class2.py
```

On windows that would look like this:

```
C:\...project2> python project1/class2.py
```

Alternatively you could modify the python path inside of `class2.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(".../project2")

from project1.class1 import class1
```

Or modify the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable similarly.

To be able to extend your project and import for example something in `subclass1.py` from `subclass2.py` you should consider starting the import paths always with `project2`, for example in `class2.py`:

```
from project2.project1.class1 import class1
```

Ofcourse you would need to adjust the methods I just showed to match the new path.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, project1 is an entirely separate project and isn't normally stored in project2 (it's actually just a git submodule there). It's also used in a third project in a similar way which has no contact with project2. So project1 should have no references to project2 and should know nothing about it. Only project2 should know about project1.

Comment: Then the first method I've shown and using the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable should still be valid options.

Comment: You're right, this *will work*, so you get the up vote for that. But I'm going to hold off on accepting it as the answer, since both running the code from a parent directory and manually editing the PYTHONPATH is a bit of work around. The code will likely be used by teammates and both of these approaches are a bit of exceptions and not super intuitive.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer as it suggest **wrong** ways of solving this problem.  You should *not* do `python package1/class1.py` but instead you should use the `-m` switch of the python interpreter and use `python -m package1.class1`. This makes sure that the package is initialized correctly. Failing to do so *can* lead to hard to debug bugs (e.g. if you use pickle or anything related to it inside `class1.py` running the code in the proposed way can break functionality).